# dynamically creating a set of SQLAlchemy tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a simple table defined with SQLAlchemy declarative:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable1'
    row_id = Column(INT, primary_key=True)
    another_column = Column(CHAR(10))
```

I'd like to create a set of tables, with these names:

```
table_names = ('mytable1', 'mytable2', 'mytable3', 'mytable4')
```

Is there a simple way to create this set of tables, all with the same column definitions (but each with its own name), without repeating the table definition?

Comment: You should not make variable names out of data, especially important data. You should be storing these tables in a dictionary.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense, I'm not sure I follow - I rehprased the question to make it more clear that I'm just looking for a way to define a set of tables with different names but the same column definitions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dictionary would be the best way to go here. Perhaps something like:

```
table_dict = {}
for i in range(4):   # Create
  table_name = "mytable" + str(i)
  table_dict[table_name] = MyTable(table_name)

for i in range(4):   # Query
  session.query(table_dict["mytable" + str(i)])
```

Something like that is probably what you're looking for. This would also let you create the dictionary keys automatically, like in a for loop.

EDIT: I assumed you were making instances of the `MyTable` class, but looking again that does not appear to be the case. I don't know the specifics of SQLAlchemy but my guess is you'll want to create `MyTable` instances using the `__init__` function.

EDIT EDIT: if you want to create multiple table objects, you could create a function to generate and return a new class. Maybe something like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()

def TableCreator(tablename):
  class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = tablename
    row_id = Column(INT, primary_key=True)
    another_column = Column(CHAR(10))
  return MyTable
```

Then you could call it with `mytable1 = TableCreator("mytable1")`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I was indeed looking for a way to define these tables using SQLAlchemy. I'm new to it, and I couldn't see a simple way to do this. I edited the question to make this more clear.