# SQLalchemy: Dynamically create tables with different set of columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I need to create several Tables in SQLalchemy ORM which all follow a similar schema:

- Each table contains the same set of shared columns (id + `shared_col1`/2)
- Each table consists of 1+ individual columns (dimensions)
- The table name and the respective dimensions are known at the time the table is created
- It can be assumed that all dimensions columns are string columns

Here's an example of a the tables are created:

```py
class SomeTable1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'dim_table1'
    
    id = Column(String(4), primary_key=True)
    shared_col1 = Column(String)
    dimension1 = Column(String, nullable=False)
    dimension2 = Column(String, nullable=False)
    shared_col2 = Column(String, nullable=False))
```

My Question: How could I create the tables dynamically, e.g. in a loop? Without having to explicitly state each table definition? Say, based on a dict like this:

```
{
  "dimension_table1": ["dimension1", "dimension2"],
  "dimension_table2": ["dimension3"],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamically creating a set of SQLAlchemy tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225320/dynamically-creating-a-set-of-sqlalchemy-tables)

Comment: already stumbled upon this question, but it states: "Is there a simple way to create this set of tables, **all with the same column definitions** (but each with its own name), without repeating the table definition?". This is not the case for my problem. Updated the title accordingly.